# Where can I find a list of CAMLvariables and ServerVariables?

Tags: caml-query

Having some trouble finding a list of these variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
More specifically, when I see this on the page:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
```

I want to know what other CAMLVariable exist. This also of course includes ServerVariables as well.

Comment: @Mike T: Can you please explain a little more about what you mean here? How are you trying to use these variables?

Comment: When editing the xslt in many of the SharePoint's pages, there are references to these variables. I am trying to find more information about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx

Comment: @Mike T, Setting up IntelliSense for CAML in Visual Studio may be a help, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507730.aspx

@next_con, I've pretty much exclusively used either U2U CAML Query Builder or SharePoint Manager 2007 to get my CAML for SPQuery...please let me know if you think of the other tool you had in mind!

Comment: I have started to use these as well. The link is a good one. However, I still would like to have a reference to ServerVariables.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being daft, but does this page actually contain a list of CAML Variables?  I can't actually find, for example, PageUrl or HttpVDir, which are both included as parameters in standard DVWP definitions.

Comment: @Dexter, I don't see either how the accepted answer actually answered the OP question. Where are these elusive CAMLVariables actually defined?

Comment: @MdMazzotti, excellent point - I dont think that this question has been answered, by either this answer or others on the page.  There is a list of Server Variables here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx (instructions for using them are in Marc D Anderson's answer below), but I still haven't found a source describing the CAML variables.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the reference to Server Variables from my blog:
http://mdasblog.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/data-view-web-part-parameters-based-on-server-variables/

Comment: Thanks Marc don't know what I was thinking accepting that other one as an answer, yours and Jaap's are the most useful replies.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide you with a list of CAMLVariables, but here is [an interesting link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609943/dynamically-set-the-defaultvalue-of-a-parameterbinding-in-a-dataformwebpart) that demonstrates a trick that allows you to be extremely flexible with regards to the values being passed into your ParameterBindings.

Comment: I just posted the same answer as above on your interesting link, Jaap.  Server Variables are going to be easier to work with than that trick, IMHO.

Comment: You are right when we only need the URL variable, but the stackoverflow answer provided at the url in my answer above shows a menthod that is not limited to the available Server Variables. You could construct ANY string in your C# code and "inject" it.

Comment: Thanks Jaap don't know what I was thinking accepting that other one as an answer, yours and Marcs are the most useful replies.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reference I can't seem to find now, but it helps to build and test your queries in something like Stramit CAML Viewer or U2U CAML Creator.

Comment: thanks mike use this all the time, the old u2u tool, cant stand the newer version.